# How to add a column to all connected nodes - mnesia table

Tags: erlang, mnesia, erl

I am trying to add new column to an existing mnesia table. For that, I use following code.

```
test()->

Transformer =
  fun(X)-> % when is_record(X, user) -> %previous users
      #userss{name = X#user.name,
           age = X#user.age,
           email = X#user.email,
          year = 1990}
end,
AF = mnesia:transform_table(user, Transformer,record_info(fields, userss),userss),

 mnesia:sync_transaction(AF).
```

Two records I have

```
-record(user,{name,age,email}).
-record(users,{name,age,email,year}).
```

I want to update all connected node's tables. But it fails.

```
{aborted,{badarg,{aborted,{"Bad transform function",user,
                           #Fun<test.2.61379004>,'otherserver@192.168.169.1',
                           {badfun,#Fun<test.2.61379004>}}},
                 [],infinity,mnesia}}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an anonymous function can only be called on nodes where the module that defines it is loaded.  I guess you loaded the module containing the `test` function only on one node in the cluster - you need to load it on all nodes for this to work.  You can use the `nl` command ("network load") instead of `l` in the Erlang shell for that:

```
nl(my_module).
```

`nl` and other commands are described [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/c.html#nl-1).

Comment: yes, this solved my issue. running `nl(module).` in lowest version if there are multiple versions of erlang solved the issue completely.